# Aptana Studio 3 with FTP

Tags: ftp, aptana

I use FTP in new Aptana 3, but I would like using with keeping directories sync while navigation? Any possible?

Answer (score 3):

If i got your question right, there is a ticket for this navigation feature at http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2955

-Max

Answer (score 0):

First off, this is not the kind of question that is expected here. SO is about specific programming issues. Just FYI.

As per the question itself, Aptana 3 manages FTP differently than Aptana 2. You assign a connection to a project and manually sync it with the FTP server whenever you need it instead of syncing any change you make on your hard disc. It saves bandwidth and lets you have a local copy with unsaved changes, pretty much like you would have with an SVN repo. If you wish, you can manually sync the local copy and the FTP server after each save (it's just a click).

Comment: Oh? Then the UI must have been improved in A3, as in A2, I've never seen the possibility to work in the same fashion as in A3.